# In R, sample n rows from a df in which a certain column has non-NA values (sample conditionally)

Tags: r, dataframe, random, subset

**Background**

Here's a toy `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 
                gender = c("f","f","m","f","m","m"), 
                zip = c(48601,NA,29910,54220,NA,44663),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

As you can see, I've got a couple of `NA` values in the `zip` column.

**Problem**

I'm trying to randomly sample 2 entire rows from `df` -- but I want them to be rows for which `zip` is not null.

**What I've tried**

This code gets me a basic (i.e. non-conditional) random sample:

```
df2 <- df[sample(nrow(df), 2), ]
```

But of course, that only gets me halfway to my goal -- a bunch of the time it's going to return a row with an `NA` value in `zip`. This code attempts to add the condition:

```
df2 <- df[sample(nrow(df$zip != NA), 2), ]
```

I think I'm close, but this yields an error `invalid first argument`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `rownames` + `na.omit` to sample the rows

```
> df[sample(rownames(na.omit(df["zip"])), 2),]
  ID gender   zip
3  c      m 29910
4  d      f 54220
```

Comment: In `na.omit` can we make it `na.omit(df$zip)`? I don't mind if other columns have `NA`, just if `zip` does.

Comment: @logjammin Okay, I see. Please check with my update.

Answer (score 8):

We can use `is.na`

```
tmp <- df[!is.na(df$zip),]
> tmp[sample(nrow(tmp), 2),]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, and it'll definitely do in a pinch, but the real dataset I'm working on has ~200m rows (and ~15 cols) and I'm wondering if making the first `tmp` is going to take a bunch of time. Let me try running it and seeing how we do.

Comment: @logjammin if it is big, why not use `data.table` i.e. `library(data.table);setDT(df)[!is.na(tmp)][sample(.N, 2)]`

Comment: I'll try that now and report back. Thanks akrun.

Comment: I get an error when running your most recent code on the real dataset (` i is invalid type (matrix)`), but thankfully your original answer actually works very well. My concerns about the speed of running `tmp <- df[!is.na(df$zip),]` on that many rows were unfounded; it only took 3 seconds or so. The subsequent `sample` took no time at all, either, and I get the new `df` I wanted out of it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @logjammin that error seems to be related to type of dataset.  i.e. `data.frame` vs `matrix`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a base R solution with `complete.cases()`

```
# define a logical vector to identify NA
x <- complete.cases(df)

# subset only not NA values
df_no_na <- df[x,]

# do the sample
df_no_na[sample(nrow(df_no_na), 2),]
```

Output:

```
  ID gender   zip
3  c      m 29910
6  f      m 44663
```

Comment: This is great, and fast. Thanks. I'm going to benchmark it against akrun's solution above and see who wins on the "real" dataset, which is fairly large (~200m x ~15).

Comment: This is indeed great.

Comment: Ah wait but suppose there are other columns with `NA` in the real dataset -- wouldn't complete cases choose only rows with every column complete (i.e. with no `NA` anywhere)? I don't care about having other `NA` in other columns, only about `zip`.

Comment: You colud do `x <- complete.cases(df[,3])`. Is only for column 3 e.g. `zip`.

Answer (score 4):

For the `tidyverse` lovers out there...

```
library("dplyr")
df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>% 
  dplyr::slice_sample(n = 2)
```

If it only NA in the `zip` column you care about, then:

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na(zip) %>% 
  dplyr::slice_sample(n = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The important thing here is to avoid creating an unnecessary second data frame with the NA values dropped.  You could use the solution using `na.omit` given in another answer, but alternatively you can use `which` to return a list of valid rows to sample from.  For example:

```
nsamp <- 23
df[sample(which(!is.na(df$zip)), nsamp), ]
```

The advantage to doing it this way is that the condition inside the `which` can be anything you like, whether or not it involves missing values.  For example this version will sample from all the rows with female gender in zip codes starting with 336:

```
df[sample(which(df$gender=='f' & grepl('^336', df$zip)), nsamp), ]
```